# "Притом, что мой оклад" или "при том, что мой оклад"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

> Материал был отмечен на редколлегии газеты как «лучший в номере», и я
> получил свой первый в жизни гонорар — 75 рублей (**притом**, что мой
> месячный оклад курьера составлял всего 70 рублей).

Это из биографии Сергея Соседова (текст взят с личного сайта Сергея).

"Притом" написано слитно. Это правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Материал был отмечен на редколлегии газеты как «лучший в номере», и я получил свой первый в жизни гонорар — 75 рублей (**притом что мой месячный оклад курьера составлял всего 70 рублей**).*

**Пояснение**

**1. Справочник по пунктуации** http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_780

**ПРИ ТОМ(,) ЧТО, союз**

В «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН рекомендуется написание **«притом что»** (слитное).

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «при том(,) что», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и **не разделяться запятой)**, но может и **расчленяться** (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом «что»).

2. Однако в приведённом примере присоединительная часть **заключена в скобки**, поэтому расчленяться союз не может.

**3. Из грамматики**

К присоединительному союзу "притом»  примыкают союзы
**«притом что»  и  «притом чтобы».**

Союз  «притом что»  имеет  дополнительное значение  **уступки**  (можно заменить союзами «хотя, несмотря на то что», союз  «притом чтобы» имеет дополнительное значение  **цели.**

**Примеры**

Стиль исполнения группы не меняется, **притом что** качество звучания постоянно улучшается.

Я хотел найти более короткую дорогу, **притом чтобы** она была проезжей.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь спрашивается о логическом обосновании:
https://korrektor-ru.livejournal.com/1442755.html

Оно такое: *при( )том, что = при том факте, что*.
Какое обоснование у авторов Орфографического словаря? Наверно, стремление к упрощению.